# When placed in drive or reverse my car will not creep

Tags: honda, pilot

2007 Honda Pilot... When I put my car in drive or reverse it will not creep. I can push on the gas and the car will move but there is a lot of resistance as if the emergency brake is on but it is not. I have to put the car in park and back in drive maybe once maybe 5x before it will release. Putting the emergency brake on and taking it off has felt like it helped the problem but then again I feel as though it was just me putting it in park to put the E brake on. Also playing with the kids and dancing in our seats has also felt like it fixed the problem, but could just be a coincidence. I have put my car in park a couple of times but not turned the car off and it doesn't lock up (so far) I have been to a mechanic and they checked the brakes and calipers and there is no discoloration, nothing showing they are sticking and nothing showing the emergency brake is sticking. They checked the transmission fluid and it was not low and was clean.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Try driving at walking speed and put the transmission in neutral. It should roll on for quite a distance. If it comes to a stop fairly quickly, it means your calipers are sticking, or something else causes a resistance.

Comment: The 2007 Pilot e-brakes are hidden drum brakes inside the rear disc brake rotor hats. It is possible the shop skipped checking that, even if they checked the linkage to it.